# C++ remove_if without iterating through whole vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, remove-if

I have a vector of pointers, pointing to approx 10MB of packets. In that, from first 2MB, I wanna delete all those that matches my predicate. The problem here is `remove_if` iterates through the whole vector, even though its not required in my use case. Is there any other efficient way?

```
fn_del_first_2MB
{
    uint32 deletedSoFar = 0;
    uint32 deleteLimit = 2000000;

    auto it = std::remove_if (cache_vector.begin(), cache_vector.end(),[deleteLimit,&deletedSoFar](const rc_vector& item){
    if(item.ptr_rc->ref_count <= 0) {
        if (deletedSoFar < deleteLimit) {
            deletedSoFar += item.ptr_rc->u16packet_size;
        delete(item.ptr_rc->packet);    
        delete(item.ptr_rc);
            return true;
        }
        else    
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
    });
    cache_vector.erase(it, cache_vector.end());
}
```

In the above code, once the `deletedSoFar` is greater than `deleteLimit`, any iteration more than that is unwanted.

Comment: Instead of `cache_vector.end()` put your own marker. There are different [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) overloads.

Comment: @RawN ^ That might be an appropriate answer with a concise code sample.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Eer I lack the *concise code sample* part. I am only half way through the Meyers first book.

Comment: You can use something else than `cache_vector.end()` for the end of the range `std::remove_if()` should work on. Note, however, that `std::remove_if()` only rearranges the content and everything between the return from `std::remove_if()` and the end position has unspecified content. You'll probably want to follow up the operation with something moving the tail forward and then `erase()`ing everything between the tail and the end.

Comment: @Dietmar ^ Same for you. I think the question is _on-topic_ and that's a considerable answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: ... but I stopped reading Meyers's STL book after a few items! ;-)

Comment: @Dietmar Good to know, not all of us are doing _cargo cult_ based coding ;-).

Comment: The one I am reading is the *Effective* one.

Comment: Re: "remove_if iterates through the whole vector" -- no, it only does that if you tell it to. `remove_if`, like all algorithms, takes a pair of iterators that define the range that it will examine. If you don't want to go through the whole vector, don't pass iterators that go through the whole vector.

Comment: Can't you have smart pointer for `item.ptr_rc` to simplify the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use your own loop:

```
void fn_del_first_2MB()
{
    const uint32 deleteLimit = 2000000;

    uint32 deletedSoFar = 0;
    auto dest = cache_vector.begin();
    auto it = dest

    for (; it != cache_vector.end(); ++it) {
        const auto& item = *it;

        if (item.ptr_rc->ref_count <= 0) {
            deletedSoFar += item.ptr_rc->u16packet_size;
            delete(item.ptr_rc->packet);    
            delete(item.ptr_rc);
            if (deletedSoFar >= deleteLimit) {
                ++it;
                break;
            }
        } else if (dest != it) {
            *dest = std::move(*it);
            ++dest;
        }
    }
    cache_vector.erase(dest, it);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an optimal solution, but when I try I end up in some other issue. However, thanks for your time.  

` backtrace:
/system/lib/libc.so (je_arena_dalloc_bin_locked+221)
/system/lib/libc.so (je_tcache_bin_flush_small+238)
/system/lib/libc.so (ifree+448)
/system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
/system/lib/smu/libwlan_core.so (_ZN15roam_scan_cache23roam_cache_delete_frontEj+220)
/system/lib/smu/libwlan_core.so (_ZN15roam_scan_cache21roam_packet_processorEPv+660)
/system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
/system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6) `

Comment: @Ananth: I think I miss a `++it` just before `break;` (edited)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `cache_vector.end()` put your own iterator marker `myIter`. With the `remove_if` option you should follow the [erase-remove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) idiom. Here is an example that affects only the first 4 elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    size_t index = 4; // index is something you need to calculate
    auto myIter = vec.begin() + index; // Your iterator instead of vec.end()
    vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), myIter, [](int x){return x < 3; }), myIter);
    // modified vector:
    for (const auto& a : vec)
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, myIter needs to be calculate at runtime, which means I need to parse once just to find myIter, and then do the actual erase-remove.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `std::remove_if()` to pass the `.end()` iterator as the second argument: as long as the first argument can reach the second argument by incrementing, any iterators can be passed.

There is somewhat of a complication as your condition depends on the accumulated size of the elements encountered so far. As it turns out, it looks as if `std::remove_if()` won't be used. Something like this should work (although I'm not sure if this use of `std::find_if()` is actually legal as it keeps changing the predicate):

```
std::size_t accumulated_size(0u);
auto send(std::find_if(cache_vector.begin(), cache_vector.end(),
                              [&](rc_vector const& item) {
        bool rc(accumulated_size < delete_limit);
        accumulated_size += item.ptr_rc->u16packet_size;
        return rc;
    });
std::for_each(cache_vector.begin(), send, [](rc_vector& item) {
       delete(item.ptr_rc->packet);    
       delete(item.ptr_rc);
    });
cache_vector.erase(cache_vector.begin(), send);
```

The `std::for_each()` could be folded into the use of `std::find_if()` as well but I prefer to keep things logically separate. For a sufficiently large sequence there could be a performance difference when the memory needs to be transferred to the cache twice. For the tiny numbers quoted I doubt that the difference can be measured.

Comment: You forget the `if (item.ptr_rc->ref_count <= 0)` condition of the OP. And so the `erase` is more complicated.